# OData in Windows UWP LoadProperty?

Tags: odata, uwp

I have an OData application and inside my Windows UWP client, the Container object does not have the LoadProperty method. It does, and works great, in the console applications in the same project file. Is this expected behavior? If so, is there a workaround other than manually loading the related entities?

Thanks.

Comment: I assume this is because of the async nature of UWP apps, but was curious if anyone has run across a workaround for this?

Comment: I think I have it, Container.BeginLoadProperty seems like the ticket.